# I am having trouble getting my nav items in the navbar to behave as expected

Tags: css

I am building a navbar with hover effects over the nav items and an inline button, however, the text in my button is not lining up with the other nav items. In addition I am having trouble figuring out how to get the red hover background to space itself evenly above and below the text of my nav items. What am I doing wrong?

```
  <nav class="navbar"> 
                <a id="header" href="#">Adopt <span class="me">Me</span> </a>
                    <ul >
                        <div id="rightitems">
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Benefits</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Buddies</a></li>
                            <button class="btn"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></button>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                    
                    </ul>
            </nav>
```

```
.btn{
        display: inline;
       width: auto;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0;
}  

.btn a{
        margin: 0;

}

body{
        background-image: url(bulldog.jpg)
}
    
a{
        text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
   
}

nav a{
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
   
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
 }

#rightitems{
        display: flex;

    }

li{
        width: auto;
}

li:hover{
       width: auto;
}

li:hover {
    background-color:  #FF4850;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
  
}

nav li:hover{
           color: white;
}
 
nav a:hover{
      color: white; 
  }
```

[image: Sample of my navbar]

Comment: Can you please try rewriting your question in light of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: Please add your HTML

Comment: Thanks for your edits, the question is clearer now. If I were to answer your question directly, I would say you would need to replace `<li><a href="#">Our Buddies</a></li>` with `<button class="btn"><a href="#">Our Buddies</a></button>` to fix one of the issues you are having. However, more helpful to you would be to suggest using the [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve what you want.

Comment: You can not nest `a` into `button`, that is invalid HTML. It looks like you don’t actually need a button here, but you simply want a link that looks like one? Then _use_ a link, and apply CSS formatting to make it _look_ like a button.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some duplicate selectors and a bit of redundant styling. I've made some adjustments check out this fiddle:

```
nav a {
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:not('me'):hover{
  color: white; 
}

.navbar #rightitems li{
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cf2vd64y/2/